# IBM RAD - Profiling an EAR application

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad, ibm-rad-7.5

I've an enterprise app with a ejb,web modules and few other modules that I'm developing using RAD 7.5.5. I want to run Profiling tool on this application deployed to Websphere App Server configured in my RAD. Which Profile configuration type should I choose to create a new configuration? I have tried selecting the Websphere AppServer 7.0 Application Client. But I get an error message saying "The Enterprise Application must contain at least one Application Client" and the Application Client module dropdown has only one entry `<Default>`. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to start server in the Profiling mode. Stop your server, and then right-click your EAR project and  instead of doing `Run on Server`, select `Profile on Server`. You can also use `Start server in profiling mode` option in the Servers view.

Answer (score 1):

For Profiling

- Start the server in Profile mode
- After starting pop up will appear -> which will ask to select Profile setting

  1. Java Profiling -> Execution, Memory, Thread etc.
  2. Health Care collector

Select Any java profiling and click next.

Open perspective in Profiling to check each request analysis view.